# Android AsyncTask gives strange behavior

Tags: android, android-asynctask, logcat, android-logcat

I am trying to make an API call to get a list of YouTube videos like this:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {
        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        final String key = "my_key";
        final String channelId = "UCoLEarNS6E-Kbzoya_p7k2Q";

        String charset = "UTF-8";           
        String response = null;

        try 
        {                           
            String query = String.format("key=%s&channelId=%s&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20", 
                     URLEncoder.encode( key, charset ) ,
                     URLEncoder.encode( channelId, charset )
                    );

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = builder.toString();      
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
             sendEmail ( "MyQuestionsActivity Network Error" , "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        return response;
    }
```

But it keeps erroring out. And if I paste the url into the browser, it returns some JSON. But in this case, the sendEmail utility I made is sending me this error from e.getMessag():

```
Error: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=my_key&channelId=UCoLEarNS6E-Kbzoya_p7k2Q&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

Would anyone know what isn't going right? Also I am having some issues with my catLog so I am not able to see the exception.

Comment: Are you sure you need conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); ? I think it's GET, since you that's what browser does when you put into it. As well as conn.setDoOutput(true); does same as set method to POST.

Comment: Good point. Trying it with a get now.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. What should I have done with the setDoOutput method? I am a bit confused about it.

Comment: Also, i think that if you setDoOutput to "true" by default takes it as POST, you should conn.setDoInput(true); and remove the dooutputs...

Comment: Still getting the same error after the suggested changes

Comment: Please provide exception/error you get.

Comment: I can't seem to get my logCat working right on this new app...trying to configure it. But the error.getMessage() just outputs the url string.

Comment: Wait, that's an http"S" request the one you are trying to do, you will always get a handshake exception with that call, you need to research how to do SSL calls using Http "S" URLConnection

Comment: Ah yes, it is https. Maybe I can just do http with the YouTube API? How much more involved is the HTTPS call?

Comment: HTTPS calls are expensive in performance since they add a robust security system, if you can just avoid it thats perfect, other way you need to implement the HTTPS request...

Comment: Just tried to see if it can be avoided, and got error that it is needed.

Comment: Here is a good example how to do your call: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Comment: Also, i recommend you to do it with HttpClient if possible, SSL connections could be quiet tricky and require a perfect understanding of certificates system, most of these issues would be automatically handled by the HttpClient unless there's special issues with the certificate, but since we are talking about google servers here, you should have no problems with that... Regards

Comment: Yeah I am reading that documntation now and I don't understand anything there LOL...all new stuff. Do you mean HttpClient and not AsyncTask?